# Linking JS file in Rail application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a 404 error in the source tab of the Chrome dev tools trying to link a JS file.  First time I'm trying this in a larger application. In my application.html.erb, I have this link:

```
<%= render 'layouts/scripts' %>
```

in the layouts/scripts file I have:

```
<script src="/javascripts/welcome.js"></script>
```

My welcome.js file is under the javascripts directory, but I keep getting a 404 error when I look in the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Put `welcome.js` into `assets/javascripts`

Then in `javascripts/application.js` make sure you have this line

`//= require_tree .`

Please read this article http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html

Comment: This is how I had it set up originally, I believe as the default.  Still not working.